# AsParallel() or async/await

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

Let's suppose to do a method `CountString` that, given an array of strings and a int, returns the number of strings whose length is greater than that int.
If I have to take advantage as far as possible of multicore hardware, is it enough to do:

```
public int CountString(string[] s, int i) 
{
  return s.AsParallel().Count( res => res.length > i);
}
```

or have i got to use somehow Tasks or even to mix task and PLinq??

It has to be considered only a simple example, i know this method not affects too much the hardware performance.

I'm wondering if it is better to do so, using `AsParallel()`, or if it is better to declare the method `async` and use the `await` (even if i don't know how) in the method body.

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2014-12-23/parallelism-async-threading-explained/  If you don't have non-blocking operations (nor a UI thread), you don't need `Task`.

Comment: Note that your work is far too trivial to benefit from parallelization.

Comment: Yes i know, it was only a pure example, it has to be considered mainly with a huge amount of strings to check... Btw i'm going to read that article, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:**

As i see your actual question was a bit misleading, i'll try answering the intentional one. Specifically here, going with `AsParallel` would be a good approach, since there isn't actually anything you need to `await`. Since you're dealing with a collection, PLINQ or Paralle.ForEach are a good choice. Consider going with `async-await` when you have naturally async I/O bound operations. It is recommended not to [wrap synchronous methods with async wrappers.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)

---

If you actually test your code, you might even be surprised to see that paralleling this piece of code actually has a *negative* performance cost on your method execution, depending on the *size* of the array you're iterating over.

Many times people forget that using threads actually has overhead, even when using threads out of the threadpool. You have to have a least amount of CPU intensive work for this to be worth taking the performance hit of your parallelization.

If your array is long enough, then using `AsParallel` should be suffice. There is no reason to be adding `Task` as PLINQ will take care of the parallalization just fine.

Ok, lets actually test this code. Im going to be iterating over a `string[]` filled with GUIDs. This is the code:

Main Method:

```
void Main()
{
    //JIT
    Test(0);

    Test(100);
    Test(1000);
    Test(10000);
    Test(1000000);
    Test(10000000);
}

public void Test(int itemAmount)
{
    string[] strings = Enumerable.Range(0, itemAmount).Select(i => Guid.NewGuid()
                                                      .ToString()).ToArray();

    var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    CountStringInParallel(strings, itemAmount);
    stopWatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Parallel Call: String amount: {0}, Time: {1}", 
                                                        itemAmount, stopWatch.Elapsed);
    
    stopWatch.Restart();
    CountStringSync(strings, itemAmount);
    stopWatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Synchronous Call: String amount: {0}, Time: {1}", 
                                                        itemAmount, stopWatch.Elapsed);
}
```

Parallel and Sync:

```
public int CountStringInParallel(string[] s, int i) 
{
    return s.AsParallel().Count( res => res.Length > i);
}

public int CountStringSync(string[] s, int i) 
{
    return s.Count(res => res.Length > i);
}
```

Results:

> Parallel Call: String amount: 100, Time: **00:00:00.0000197**
>
> Synchronous Call: String amount: 100, Time: **00:00:00.0000026**

---

> Parallel Call: String amount: 1000, Time: **00:00:00.0000266**
>
> Synchronous Call: String amount: 1000, Time: **00:00:00.0000201**

---

> Parallel Call: String amount: 10000, Time: **00:00:00.0002060**
>
> Synchronous Call: String amount: 10000, Time: **00:00:00.0002003**

---

> Parallel Call: String amount: 1000000, Time: **00:00:00.0080492**
>
> Synchronous Call: String amount: 1000000, Time: **00:00:00.0135279**

---

> Parallel Call: String amount: 10000000, Time: **00:00:00.0744104**
>
> Synchronous Call: String amount: 10000000, Time: **00:00:00.1402474**

You can see that up to 10,000 strings, the synchronous method is actually faster then the parallel.

Comment: surely that would depend on the length of `s`. There's sure to be a cutoff beyond which parallelization yields benefit, even for such a trivial workload.

Comment: Why would you think OP's code will have negative performance (assuming `s` array is large not very small)?

Comment: @spender If the op has to do a `Count` operation on a huge list of strings, i would thing a different solution should be suggested instead of parallizing an array traversal.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov What would that different solution be? Can you be specific; because I can't think of one

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I guess you're overlooking the OP's code. OP is checking each string's `Length` property in a string array, not count of the collection. There is no better way than what OP is doing if the array happens to be large.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Oh, you're right. My bad. I've added some benchmarks to the code example to clear my point. I should of made it clear that it isn't *always* the case that sync is better than parallel of course.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry i didn't write the question correctly initially. So, with collections is usually better to use PLINQ i suppose, talking about parallelism/concurrency. If more methods were involved probably the situation would have changed.

Comment: @Sanci It really depends on the situation. When you're processing in a pipeline or producer-consumer pattern, looking at TPL Dataflow would be helpfull. When you have IO bound operations, `async-await` fits. When you have collections, you can pick whichever feels better, you can either go with `PLINQ` or `Parallel.ForEach`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't use `async-await` `AsParallel` is all you need. There's no reason to use tasks directly as `AsParallel` does that for you under the hood.

It's important to remember that parallelism has an overhead which in your case would probably be bigger than the added value of parallelism. For parallelism to actually improve performance, you should be working on many items, and the work itself should be non-trivial.

If you do, however, need to use `async-await` `AsParallel` (and the rest of PLinq) doesn't fit as it predates the TAP. You would need to use `Task.Run` to parallelize the processing and `Task.WhenAll` to `await` for it all. Similar to this:

```
var tasks = items.Select(item => Task.Run(() => Process(item));
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
// process results
```

Comment: My question is probably bad written. I wanted to ask indeed if it was better to declare the method as async and use (i don't know how) 'await' inside the method or to do just as i did, using AsParallel().

Comment: @Sanci as long as there's nothing truly asynchronous in there which is usually I/O there's no sense in using async-await.